# Typing a function with an interface of type in flowjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, types, flowtype, type-systems

I have had quite a few look at the flow documentation, with some question still in mind.
I have write a constructor named **Track** ;with my best attempt to type annotate it
still not fully understanding it.

Here is the code:

```
javascript
//@flow
"use strict";
/**
 *A track is compatible with
 * other track and can be parsed to
 *a higher order function using the
 * `this keyword.
 */
type ITrack<T> = {
  x: T,
  y: T,
  width: T,
};

 /**
 * A Track is an adjustable and join-able imaginary ray
 * That stretches out indefinite with a fixed starting x position.
 *@Function Track
 *@Param x -The x position to place the track
 *@Param y - The y position to palce the track
 *@Param width - The width of the track.
 **/

function Track<ITrack> (x, y, width) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = width;
}
```

Comment: Firslty,I would like to justify my intention,I am building a tree widget from the html5 canvas.
it must sit on a Track

Answer (score 0):

To annotate a function in flow, you would actually do this inline. Something like this would probably suit you better

```
// @flow

function Track(x: number, y: number, width: number): void {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = width;
}
```

What you were trying to do before was create a type that accepted generics, but T could then be a range of types like it could be all booleans and that's not really what you want I imagine.

Comment: After you wrote that,i have come up with a solution involving generics:

```javascript

function Track<T:number>(x: number, y: number, width: number): T {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = width;
  return this;
}
```

Comment: you can check you types with flow check <dirname> of the project